# Antlr4 allocate ParseTree on heap

Tags: c++, memory-management, antlr4, abstract-syntax-tree

I have a function like this to get the the AST from a file.

```
antlr4::tree::ParseTree *get_ast(std::string &filename) {
    std::ifstream stream;
    stream.open(filename);
    antlr4::ANTLRInputStream input(stream);
    Lexer lexer(&input);
    antlr4::CommonTokenStream tokens(&lexer);
    Parser parser(&tokens);
    antlr4::tree::ParseTree *tree = parser.program();
    return tree;
}
```

But when using the return value, it seems that what tree is pointing to is already cleared (on the stack), and I need to know how to allocate the tree on the heap, so I can use the return value (and manually free).

**EDIT**: based on @sepp2k comment, I tried keeping the parser alive by heap allocating.

```
Parser *get_parser(std::string filename) {
    std::ifstream stream;
    stream.open(filename);
    antlr4::ANTLRInputStream input(stream);
    Lexer lexer(&input);
    antlr4::CommonTokenStream tokens(&lexer);
    return new Parser(&tokens);
```

}

However, this now gives segmentation fault in Parser.cpp generated file when I call a rule from the parser

Comment: The trees that are created by the parser are owned by the parser object. So in order to keep the trees alive, you'll need to keep the parser alive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You not only have to keep the parser alive but also the token stream, because the parse tree uses token references.

I recommend to create a wrapper class holding all the parser related objects and keep that alive. This way all the references stay valid. You can always re-use the object for new parse runs.

For [MySQL Workbench I created a parser context](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-workbench/blob/8.0/modules/db.mysql.parser/src/mysql_parser_module.cpp#L115) which provides all parsing functionality for the application. Use this as a template for your implementation.

Comment: Worked great! I had to keep antlr4::ANTLRInputStream, antlr4::CommonTokenStream, lexer, and parser alive

Comment: Awesome, this took me a while to realize!